# cakephp restful service

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have created a method that I want to expose to outside world. My application is controlled by ACL. so to consume restful service you send the data in get or post to that method via url. 
`http://mysite.com?action=this&data=this` etc
but I think I need to send the username and password too with it dont I? Also if I do, then where do I add it?

** WHAT HAVE I TRIED **

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://test.local/sites/loginData");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password'); 
// sending username and pwd.                   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                          
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Sample Code');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);      
curl_close($ch);
echo '<br><br>';
echo $output;
?>
```

but it doesnt show me any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using http basic auth you have to configure the auth component in CakePHP properly to use that authentication mechanism.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authentication for authentication

and this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authorization-handlers for authorization via ACL.